# Spring boot health endpoint for SOLR

Tags: spring, solr, spring-boot

I using Spring boot embedded tomcat and SOLR for dummy example.
In my configuration class I have used

```
@Bean
public CloudSolrServer solrServer(){
    return  new CloudSolrServer(zkEnsemble);
}
```

While hitting the health URL below is the message am getting.

```
{
  "status" : {
    "status" : "DOWN"
  },
  "details" : {
    "error" : "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No collection param specified on request and no default collection has been set."
  },
  "error" : "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No collection param specified on request and no default collection has been set."
}
```

Could you please assist, how can I remove this message so that status can be UP.

While investigating spring boot solr health indicator class, it was found out that `SolrHealthIndicator` does not use collection

Please assist if I am missing something

Comment: Is the Solr bean properly initialized or it's not working at all either?

Comment: it looks like you configuration of Solr is wrong. Do you need Cloud features? I recommend to try with base HttpSolrServer

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot's `SolrHealthIndicator` simply calls `ping()` on your `SolrServer`. At the moment, it has no way of knowing what collection it should be pinging (or if it should be pinging multiple collections).

Your best option just now would be to configure your `CloudSolrServer` instance with a default collection by calling `setDefaultCollection(String)` in your `solrServer()` bean method.

If you'd like to see some enhancements to `SolrHealthIndicator`, for example to allow you to configure the collection(s) to ping in `application.properties`, please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues).